# Assign incremental integers as Column headers - Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, int, assign

I am trying to **automatically** `assign` `integers` as `column` `headers` to a `pandas df` after a specific `string`. I can do this manually by reading and counting the amount of `columns` in any one `df`. e.g.

```
df.columns=['X',1,2,3...]
```

But I want to achieve this automatically without having to `count` the number of `columns`. The first `column` should be a `string` and then automatically assign incremental `integers` to the other columns..

I attempted to achieve this using a combination of @kudeh's suggestion.

```
df.columns = 'X' + [i for i in range(1,len(df.columns)+1)]
```

But this returns an error:

```
df.columns = 'X' + [i for i in range(1,len(df.columns)+1)]

TypeError: must be str, not list
```

Intended Output:

```
df.columns = ['X',1,2,3...]
```

Comment: I have to manually count the `columns` and insert `df.columns['X',1,2,n]`. I want to automatically `assign` the `columns` without having to count them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cols = ['X']
otherCols = [i for i in range(1,len(df.columns))]
cols.extend(otherCols)

df.columns = cols
```

Comment: Sorry @kudeh. I didn't explain the question properly. I've amended it now